# Postgresql - insert when not match and returning pid

Tags: postgresql

I need to insert when not match and returning new pid or matched pid (serial datatype), how to do this in postgresql?

I tried:

```
Insert Into users (email, passwd, active) 
Values ('test@example.com', 'testpwd', false) 
ON Conflict (email) Do Update 
Set Passwd='testpwd', Active=false
```

please help

thanks a lot in advance
Don

Comment: hmm.. I found it :) .. just add returning pid :)

Insert Into users (email, passwd, active) 
Values ('test@example.com', 'testpwd', false) 
ON Conflict (email) Do Update 
Set Passwd='testpwd', Active=false
Returing pid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it.. :)

```
Insert Into users (email, passwd, active) 
Values ('test@example.com', 'testpwd', false) 
ON Conflict (email) Do Update 
Set Passwd='testpwd', Active=false
Returning pid
```